# Why I am not getting the $index value in my directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive something like this:

```
.directive('grapharea', function () {
return {
    restrict:'C',
    compile: function (element, attr) {
        debugger;
        //here attr.passed is graph_${{row.id}} instead of graph_1 or graph_2 ...
        return function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

        };
    }
};
})
```

Here is my ng-repeat code:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <div id="graph_{{$index}}" data-passed="{{row.passed}}" data-failed="{{row.failed}}" class="grapharea"></div>
</div>
```

**Question:** Why I am not getting the $index value in my directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compile function is executes once for a directive. I think you want to use the link function because that is called for each use of the directive instead only once when the directives is compiled.